# How can I correctly set the user type when switching through applications that have the same session cookie name?

Tags: oracle-apex

Previously I had different applications that were part of one single project.

Every application had it's own login page. At every new login, the user were given its role (taken from the DB), like `ADMIN`, `MANAGER`, or `USER`.

Now I've created one single login page that is responsible for the login of all the applications. The user is logged only once, and all the applications are tied together through some links to the different applications. To achieve this, I gave the same session cookie name to all the related applications.

**Question:**

It is possible that one user is defined as `ADMIN` in one app and defined as `MANAGER` in another one.

When switching applications, how can I reassign the correct `user type` to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use authorization schemes and apply a separate one to each app which checks the relevant credentials for that particular app.